# Testing if two Java Objects can be compared to each other

Tags: java, generics, polymorphism, comparable

I have two values in Java, which can be any type (except primitives), so they're both of type Object. I want to see if either implements Comparable, and if so, call the compareTo() method to compare them.

However, because Comparable is a generic interface, two Objects could implement, for example, Comparable and Comparable, and not be comparable to each other.

Is there any way to determine whether two Objects are comparable to each other?

As I've thought about this, I've realized there's probably a better way to do this that involves using some type other than Object, but at this point, I'm just curious about the problem I've presented.

Comment: Your question may in fact be an [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) where you ask "how do I fix this code problem" when the best solution is to use a different approach entirely. Consider telling us the overall problem that you're trying to solve rather than how you're currently trying to solve it. My guess is that there's a design pattern or two lurking in the background just wanting to be used.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Yeah, it definitely is, so this question is now more about idle curiosity than an actual intent to use this code. I'm currently looking into better solution to this problem, and if that doesn't pan out, I'll post another question with more details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With reflection you can find the generic type of the Comparable interface.

Other lazy option is to just call it and catch the ClassCastException :)

Comment: "With reflection you can find the generic type of the Comparable interface." I think what you mean is to go through the inheritance hierarchy of one of the classes to find the type argument which it implemented `Comparable` with, and then use that to check the other object. That would only work if the type argument to the `Comparable` interface were a concrete reifiable type. If the type argument were a parameterized type or type variable, then there would be no way to check an object against it at runtime.

Comment: Sure there are limitations, but since the op was just curious... Comparable shouldn't be implemented with parameterized types too often though, as that usually has wierd side effects (kinda like making an equals() that doesn't reject subclasses...)

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is:

- You can use [Class.isAssignableFrom()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/class_isassignablefrom.htm) in order to determine if your two objects X and Y are of "compatible" classes
- You could then check, if they actually implement the Comparable interface

To then assume that calling that method on one of the two objects actually results in a reasonable result.

But honestly, I am with the comments here: this sounds like a *strange* idea; and it *feels* like you should better step back and look for better ways to solve your **real** problem. Trying to find "generic" ways how to compare apples and rocks isn't exactly easy.